# PgJDBC: "no suitable driver found" when following tutorial, why?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm writing a Java program that queries a PostgreSQL database. I'm following [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) and have trouble here:

```
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb", "mkyong",
                "123456");
```

According to the [JavaDoc for DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the first string is "a database url of the form `jdbc:subprotocol:subname`. When I connect to the server I type in `psql -h dataserv.abc.company.com -d app -U emp24` and give the password `qwe123` (for example sake). What should the first argument of `getConnection` be?

I've tried

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://dataserv.abc.company.com",  "emp24",
                    "qwe123");
```

and get the run time error: `no suitable driver found`.

I've download JDBC4 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.2-1000.

---

After I fixed my program to load the driver with `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` it recognises the JDBC URL but it still doesn't connect. I now have a new error.

When I run the program there is an error and here is the output with the stack trace:

```
-------- PostgreSQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output consoleorg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:23)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at DatabaseConnect.main(DatabaseConnect.java:32)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:60)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:101)
    ... 11 more
```

I format the URL for the `getConnection` like this:

`"jdbc:postgresql://dataserv.abc.company.com:5432/app"`

Comment: Make sure the driver is either in the classpath of Java or the application

Comment: I highly suggest going through the Oracle tutorial on the subject: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Comment: @Celeritas Probably because the PgJDBC manual covers it all pretty well. I was about to downvote it as a question with no research effort and an obvious answer, but was surprised to see that Google searches for "no suitable driver found" don't immediately point out that you probably never registered the driver, and there's no really obvious "this is what you're doing wrong" question that comes up in a Stack Overflow search either. So it's fair enough. It still feels like a bit of a "please read the manual for me" question, though. I haven't downvoted, but nearly did.

Comment: Please do not edit a question to replace it with a new question when you get past your first problem. That will confuse other people who are looking for answers to the same problem later, and causes the answers to make no sense because the question has changed. Stack Overflow is a collaboratively edited learning environment for *everyone* not just you; please think about others who might have the same problem later. If you resolve a problem and have a new problem, **post a new question** and link back to the old one.  I have reverted your change and added an explanation to the new text.

Comment: Removed my downvote on reconsideration, but you really need to start thinking about how to behave on this site or you'll start seeing people skipping over your questions. SO isn't here to help you interactively debug your code, it's for focused question-and-answer issues when *you've already done some reading and testing yourself and have been unable to work the answer out*.

Comment: Alright, I'll make a new question if I get a different error from now on. It turned out that the server is firewalled and I have to copy the program over locally before I can run it.

Comment: If you'd like to further assist me [I made a new question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115613/running-java-program-from-linux-command-line-that-requires-an-aditional-file)

Comment: Remember also to check that you are using the Correct Driver depending on your Java Version. In my case, using Java 7, I had to download [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.0.0) dependency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have failed to register the JDBC driver with the DriverManager, so JDBC doesn't know how to handle `jdbc:postgresql:`. Try `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` before you try to use `DriverManager.getConnection`. That is shown in the example code you linked to (it's the very first line), is explained in the preamble of the [DriverManager documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html), and is also explained in detail in the PgJDBC documentation linked below.

Alternately, maybe you've typo'd `jdbc:postgresql:` so the DriverManager is looking for a driver named `postgrsql` or `Postgresql` or something, which won't be registered.

Finally, you could be swallowing a class loading exception so the driver load fails and you don't see it, like this (extremely bad) code:

```
// Very bad code, never do this
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
} catch (ClasNotFoundException ex) {}
```

**Never do the above**. Either wrap the exception in an unchecked runtime exception or just add `throws ClasNotFoundException` to your method definition.

---

As per the [PgJDBC documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/index.html) and [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), to use the driver you must:

- [Download the JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html);
- [Ensure that the JDBC driver is on your `CLASSPATH`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/classpath.html);
- [Load/register the driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/load.html) by passing a JVM parameter or using `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` so it's registered with the DriverManager;
- [Connect to the database](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/connect.html)

These are all links to the manual.

For more on the `CLASSPATH`, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))

The JDBC `DriverManager` is discussed in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) and the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

---

As for the JDBC URL format for PostgreSQL, [that's in the documentation too](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/connect.html).

> With JDBC, a database is represented by a URL (Uniform Resource
>   Locator). With PostgreSQL™, this takes one of the following forms:
>
> `jdbc:postgresql:database`
>   `jdbc:postgresql://host/database`
>   `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database`

The docs go on to explain what each parameter means and the optional connection parameters.

From this you can see, in answer to your comment on John Woo's answer, that *you do not have to specify the port* if your server is listening on the default PostgreSQL port, which it is if you don't have to specify the port when connecting with `psql`.

That makes your `getConnection` arguments correct, the problem is that you didn't register the driver first.

Comment: I keep getting a SQLException. I'm just guessing the port is the default 5432, how do you actually determine the port?

Comment: @Celeritas ... and the SQLException is? Full trace? As for the port: You either check what port the `postgres` process is listening on, examine `postgresql.conf`, or run `SHOW port;` in a connected `psql`.

Comment: I edited my original question to include the stack trace. To me it looks like there's an error in the way I'm logging in with `getConnection()` but I'm sure the port, host name, user name and password are correct. Could it be the machine I'm connecting to is behind a firewall? Normally I ssh into a machine on the network before using psql.

Comment: @Celeritas Well, that isn't "the runtime error `no suitable driver found`". Which is it? Connection refused, or no suitable driver found? Or is this issue resolved and you're asking about something new and different?

Comment: @Celeritas Then the issue you were asking about is resolved and you have a new problem. The DriverManager is recognising the `jdbc:postgresql:` URL and using PgJDBC to attempt to establish a connection, which it was not doing before. `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect` suggests that you have firewall issues. Make sure you can connect with `psql` to verify you have the settings right. I cannot help you with interactively debugging your setup. If you continue to have problems *and* you can connect remotely with `psql -h dataserv.abc.company.com app`, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file has an entry for local connections, something like this:

```
local      mydatabasename  myusername  password
```