# Running Java program from Linux command line that requires an additional file

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, jdbc

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) to make a program that interacts with the database. I am stuck at the last step where I run it. The given example is
`C:\test>java -cp c:\test\postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc4.jar;c:\test JDBCExample`

I have both the .class file and the .jar for the JDBC in my home directory. I tried

`java -cp /home/JohnF/postgresql-9.2-1000.jdbc4.jar;/home/JohnF/QueryDB.class`  and I get "cannot exectue binary file"
I tried
`java -cp /home/JohnF/postgresql-9.2-1000.jdbc4.jar;/home/JohnF/QueryDB`  and I get "no such file or directory"
I tried
`java -cp /home/JohnF/postgresql-9.2-1000.jdbc4.jar;/home/JohnF QueryDB`  and I get "JohnF is a directory"

I used `chmod` to set the file permissions to `777`. How do I get this to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using semicolon as classpath separator - this will not work on Linux.
Try replacing ";" with ":" in classpath and it should work.

**Edit:** explanation of what is happening here.
  In Linux, ";" is command separator. Your line of

`java -cp /home/JohnF/postgresql-9.2-1000.jdbc4.jar;/home/JohnF QueryDB`

is really expanded into 2 executed one by one:

```
java -cp /home/JohnF/postgresql-9.2-1000.jdbc4.jar
/home/JohnF QueryDB
```

First one does nothing and successfully quits.
Second tries to invoke `/home/JohnF` as executable, and this is really not an executable, but a directory!

Comment: Note that if you double-quote the whole string it won't split it into two commands, but it'll still be wrong, because the classpath must be colon-separated on UNIX-like programs as per the introductory documentation for Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 1):

FIX: Use : instead of **;**

WHY? The file-separator in *nix environment is '**:**' and not '**;**'